# how can i make a list item visible when input checked

Tags: html, css

good day, so I have an HTML code where I list out several questions. I have a sub-list where those questions are answered but I have those answers hidden until the user clicks on the question. The user can only see one question answer at a time. The way I am setting out to achieve this is through a list of radio input tags, that when checked should reveal the hidden sentences. The problem for me is I am having trouble making the answer visible again. I've tried several combinations of selectors and that didn't work. The best I have been able to achieve was being able to click on a word and color it red, or somehow revealing all of the hidden text on the page even though nothing is checked.

```css
body{
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: "Kumbh Sans", sans-serif;
line-height: 1.4;
background: linear-gradient(365deg,hsl(261, 98%, 58%),hsl(283, 74%, 52%));
height: 100vh;
}
div{
background: white;
border-radius: 30px;
margin: auto;
width: 1200px;
}
h1{
text-align: center;
padding-top: 30px;

}
ul{
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
margin: 10px;
}
ul li input{/*makes the checkboxes invisible*/
visibility: hidden;
}
ul li label{
cursor: pointer;
}
ul li ul {/*makes the words invisible*/
font-size: 12px;
visibility: hidden;
}
input:checked+ ul li ul/*makes the words visible again*/
{
visibility: visible;
}
img{/*floats the img to the left*/
float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumbh+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <title>Frontend Mentor | FAQ Accordion Card</title>
</head>
<body >  
    <img src= 'woman.png' alt="accordian" />
<div class= "box">
    <h1>FAQ</h1>
    
    <ul>
        <li><input type='radio' name='accordian' id= 'radio1'/><label for ='radio1'>How many team members can I invite?</label>
            <ul class='display'>
                <li>You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on 
                    team members for the Premium plan.</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><input type ='radio' name= 'accordian' id= 'radio2'/><label for='radio2'>What is the maximum file upload size</label>
            <ul>
                <li>What is the maximum file upload size?
                    No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><input type ='radio' name= 'accordian' id= 'radio3'/><label for='radio3'>How do I reset my password?</label>
            <ul>
                <li>Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password” from your profile page.
                    A reset link will be emailed to you.</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><input type ='radio' name ='accordian' id= 'radio4'/><label for= 'radio4'>Can I cancel my subscription?</label>
            <ul>
                <li>Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions asked.</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><input type ='radio' name ='accordian' id= 'radio5'/><label for = 'radio5'>Do you provide additional support.</label>
            <ul>
                <li>Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal business hours.</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>   
  
</body>
</html>
```

And here is a picture of my project
[image]

Answer (score 1):

## The Issue.

**Problem 1**
`+` CSS selector will select an element that is placed immediately after. `input:checked + ul li ul` will select the `ul` if it's placed immediately after the `input:checked` element. In your HTML the `label` element is proceeding `input:checked`, not `ul`. See the following reference from w3schools for clarification: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

```
<input type='radio' name='accordian' id= 'radio1'/><label for ='radio1'>How many team members can I invite?</label>
```

**Problem 2**
Your CSS is not grabbing the correct element. The following CSS is grabbing a `ul` element immediately following the `input:checked` element, then grabbing an internal `li` and `ul`. The `li` and `ul` does not exist within the HTML scope.

```
input:checked + ul li ul/*makes the words visible again*/
{
visibility: visible;
}
```

## How to Fix.

There are two possible methods to fix this. The first is to move `input` after `label`. The second is to use the `~` selector is instead.

**Fix 1**
Change where the input is positioned and update the CSS selector accordingly. If you use this solution you may need to update additional CSS to keep your aesthetic.

HTML

```
    <li><label for ='radio1'>How many team members can I invite?</label>
        <input type='radio' name='accordian' id= 'radio1'/>
        <ul class='display'>
            <li>You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on 
                team members for the Premium plan.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

CSS

```
input:checked + ul /*makes the words visible again*/
{
visibility: visible;
}
```

**Fix 2**
Use `~` Instead. The `~` selector will grab all elements immediately following the call. `input:checked ~ ul` will grab all ul elements following input:checked inside it's scope.

CSS

```
input:checked ~ ul /*makes the words visible again*/
{
visibility: visible;
}
```